# install superset 3.0 without building assets with npm

Tags: python, npm, apache-superset

I am trying to install apache-superset and following the guidelines on installing from sratch in their website https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch/:

I manage to get everything done up to this step:

```
# Build javascript assets
cd superset-frontend
npm ci
npm run build
cd ..
```

I am having problems with build process in node , and was wondering if I can install install superset only with pip and copy the static assets from somewhere to the right directory?

Comment: I'm having the same confusion, there's no clear answer anywhere and it's required if you want to change the Superset logo or any front-end asset

Comment: I finally managed to get working by building the static assets. Only way I found because the the static assets are nowhere to be found